# Sharepoint logging authenticated users off from page to page, requiring re-entering of credentials

Tags: authentication

So myself and a few other guys on my web team have been having an issue where on some of our SP sites at seemingly random times, we'll be navigating around and it will log us off for no reason. We'll log back in, which will help us for a few more page clicks, but then all of a sudden as we arrive at another page we'll be logged out.  Sometimes it will be bad. Here are the some symptoms:

-That used to happen less frequently and would be resolved by a simple refresh, but it has gotten bad enough where that doesn't help much anymore.

-It's not browser specific, but it seems to be the worst for me in my main browser, Chrome.

-It's really hard to replicate because it happens so sporadically

-Clearing your cache and cookies and such seems to help for a little bit, but it comes back soon enough. I need to look into this one more

-It doesn't happen on all of our SP sites, only some. Can't see a correlation between why some would have this issue and some wouldn't.

-We think our non-admin clients are starting to have issues with this as well, which is causing big problems.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a load balancer/proxy between the users and SharePoint?

Comment: What version/edition of SP is in use? What is authentication method used?

Comment: We're running SP 2013 and authenticating to our school active directory. 
I'm not sure about a balancer/proxy between us and SP.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Turns out the bootstrap references we were including in the master page was doing that.